# Html pattern not null and not negative

Tags: html, css, input, pattern-matching, haml

How can i write such pattern:

- 1) Not negative: so only numbers from 1 to 999
- 2) Null Can't be first  char
- 3) Non empty field

For example:
01, , -1, 1500, abc, etc - are false

Now i have only digit checking:

```
:pattern => "[0-9]{1,4}"
```

So how to write my pattern?

Comment: Whatever this is, it's not HTML.

Comment: @Marcin it's HAML, and there is no difference in patter'n! you edition is not good here!

Comment: @Marcin html5 inputs can have a `pattern` attribute

Comment: Non empty field -> just add the "required" attribute

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa yes i added this.... just for thinking... maybe it could be done via patterns

Comment: @ValdisAzamaris if you want to dispute a question close, insulting comments is absolutely the wrong approach. You can *politely* ask on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ why it was closed and what can be done to have it reopened.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you mean that a sign (+ or -) is not allowed and that “Null Can't be first char” means that the input must not start with digit zero (0) unless the input is exactly 0, here’s the HTML code:

```
<input pattern="0|[1-9]\d{0,2}" required>
```